# Read html from file and append to just before closing body tag?

Tags: jquery

I have this Twitter single event website tag code. Currently I have it saved in a html document `twitter-complete-registration-tag.html` but I could store it anywhere.

```
<!-- Twitter single-event website tag code -->
<script src="" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<noscript>
    <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none;" alt="" src="https://analytics.twitter.com/" />
    <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none;" alt="" src="" />
</noscript>
<!-- End Twitter single-event website tag code -->
```

How can I insert this html to just before `</body>` in `document` using jquery (or vanilla javascript)?

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you have to use `.append()`

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/append/

```
$( "body" ).append( "<b>Some HTML</b>" );
```

**Attempt for adding content which loaded via Ajax:**

I dont your correct purpose. Here is an attempt how you maybe solve your task:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "twitter-complete-registration-tag.html",
  dataType: "text", 
  success: function(response) {
     $( "body" ).append( response );
  }  
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you complement your answer with how  you get html from a file into append() and why you choose to wrap the html with <b>?

Comment: "<b>" was just for this example that you can add here HTML. Check my update please.